# Guessing Game C# Enter

Tags: c#

I have a question, how to set the condition that if the user presses "Enter" when guessing a number, the program would ask "Enter a number"!

```
Program randomNumberA = new Program();
        int r = randomNumberA.RandomNumber();

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Take a guess.\n");
    string n = userNumberA.UserNumber();
    int num;
    int.TryParse(n, out num);
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

    if (IsAllDigits(n))
    {
        if (num > r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high!\n");
            userGuess++;
        }
        if (num < r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low!\n");
            userGuess++;
        }
        if (num == r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Good job, {name}! You guessed my number in {userGuess} guesses!");
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (!IsAllDigits(n) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) || !char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number!");
        continue;
    }
} while (userGuess <= USER_LIMIT);

if (userGuess > USER_LIMIT)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");
}
```

This logic checks the game, but still does not work if the user presses the "Enter" button

Comment: Can use `switch`

Comment: Are you checking for a valid entry (i.e., non empty value) or a key press?

Comment: I suppose you want to check if user pressed the enter-key, not if user types `"enter"` into your program?

Comment: An empty value and key press

Comment: The code you've posted, while not ideal, should work as you expect. Please describe the exact behavior you're seeing, and include enough sample code that we can copy-paste into a new solution to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `userNumberA.UserNumber()`? Can you please replace that with a hard-coded string?

Comment: Can `IsAllDigits(n)` be replaced with `n.All(char.IsNumber)`? If not, can include the method? Also, what is `r`?

Comment: Throughout all your code, you're only comparing the value of `num` (which is the `int` value of `n`) to `r`. You aren't evaluating any input from the console, except in your last `else if` statement.

Comment: `private static bool IsAllDigits(string n)
        {
            foreach (char c in n)
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }`

Comment: To begin with, the !IsAllDigits(n) in the else it isnt needed you re already enforcing that because you are checking whether it happens or not with the if itself. In the else if, change !char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar) for key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter and check if that works

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is slightly incomplete, but you're comparing the result of `userNumberA.UserNumber()` to `r` and not using `key` until the very last `else if` condition, which is confusing.

I think your logic can be changed slightly. Here is a sample with some hard-coded values that you should be able to leverage in your existing code:

```
private static Random _random = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Pick a random number between 1 and 100 for the user to guess
    int secretNumber = _random.Next(1, 101);

    int USER_LIMIT = 3;
    int userGuess = 0;

    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    while (userGuess < USER_LIMIT)
    {
        userGuess++;
        Console.Write("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ");
        int num;

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
        {
            if (num > secretNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high!\n");
            }
            else if (num < secretNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nGood job, {name}! That only took {userGuess} guesses!");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number!");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nGame Over!");
    if (userGuess == USER_LIMIT) Console.WriteLine($"\nThe number was: {secretNumber}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```